# Is there any method to store data in usestate after getting from api?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am using one usestate data into another usestate input , as i want the values of the input fields first to be same as getting in the api data and after that user changes it and updates the data.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [memberfee,setMemberFee]=useState({
    AUD:data[0].AUD,
    CAD:"92.8",
    CHF:"69.14",
    EUR:"63.03",GBP:"54.22",KWD:"22.49",TRY:"648.18",USD:"74.65",XNA:"100000",NewMembershipInvest:"20",MembershipYearlyInvest:"1"})

  
    
  var name,value;
  const handleInputs=e=>{
    name=e.target.name;
    value=e.target.value;
    setMemberFee({...memberfee,[name]:value})
  }

  const submitForm=()=> {
    const {AUD ,CAD ,CHF ,EUR ,GBP ,KWD ,TRY ,USD ,XNA ,NewMembershipInvest ,MembershipYearlyInvest }=memberfee;
    var doc = {
        AUD ,CAD ,CHF ,EUR ,GBP ,KWD ,TRY ,USD ,XNA ,NewMembershipInvest ,MembershipYearlyInvest 
    };
  
    axios.put('/memfeeput', doc)
    .then( res => {
      alert('Updated successfully!');
     }   
    )
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.response);
      alert('An error occurred! Try submitting the form again.');
    });
  }

    useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchBooks() {
        const response = await fetch('/memfeeget');
        const json = await response.json();
        setData(json.mf2);
        console.log(json.mf2)
    }
    fetchBooks();
},[]);
```

The line 4 code `AUD:data[0].AUD,` is giving the error as the `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AUD')` just because the API haven't got the data at that moment and didn't stored in `data usestate` . Are there any other methods of solving this issue? As mentioned above i want the data of the input fields first to be same as API one then it changes to other value and updated.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation, beyond cleaning the code up a bit, would be to set the starting state of `data` on your first line so that line 4 has an "AUD" property to read.

```js
const [data, setDate] = useState([
    {"AUD": ""}
]);
```

This way when the page loads initially it is set to the empty string, then your API will replace it as soon as you fetch the `/memfeeget` data.

Comment: It didnt work as it is not updating the data usestate even after fetching the API data

Comment: Are you sure it's not updating the data object? `setData(json.mf2)` would definitely update `data` with whatever is in `json.mf2`.

It's possible that _is_ updating the `data` object, but you are not updating the relevant input field when the data object changes. You seem to have code to update `data` object upon user input, but I do not see any code to update the input field upon `data` change.

Comment: <Form.Control size="sm" type="text" name="AUD" placeholder="Small hytext" value={memberfee.AUD} onChange={e=>handleInputs(e)}/>  . This is the input field where it is using the usestate memberfee data.